# Distance from the origin to a plane... where is my logic wrong here?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm going through MIT's multivariable calc online course, and came to the following recitation question:

> Compute the distance from P = (0,0,0) to the plane with equation $2x+y-2z=4$

The correct answer is $\frac{4}{3}$, and the TA solves this by picking a random point on the plane, drawing a vector from the origin to that point, then computing the dot product between that vector and the normal vector $<2, 1, -2>$ to find the projection in the direction of the normal vector.  Makes sense, okay.

But the way I did it originally still seems right to me, even though I'm getting the wrong answer.  The shortest path to the plane is a perpendicular vector that starts at $(0,0,0)$ and ends on the plane.  So I solved the simple equation below:

$$2\alpha + \alpha - 2\alpha = 4$$

No matter what $\alpha$ is, the left side of the equation will be parallel to the normal vector.  In this case, $\alpha = 4$, and so I get the vector $<8, 4, -8>$.  If you start it at the origin, it does indeed land on the plane with the correct normal vector direction.  Then, distance = $\sqrt{8^2 + 4^2 + (-8)^2} = 12$.  I'm clearly thinking about this incorrectly.  But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a vector in the normal direction from the origin gives $\langle 2\alpha,\alpha,-2\alpha\rangle$.  The condition that this vector ends on the plane is $2(2\alpha) + \alpha -2(-2\alpha) = 4$, i.e., $9\alpha = 4$, or $\alpha = \frac{4}{9}$.  Thus the vector is $\langle \frac89, \frac49, \frac{-8}{9}\rangle$, with length $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: Both good answers... thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(8,4,-8)$ is not on the plane $2x+y-2z=4$. Your equation should have been $4\alpha + \alpha + 4 \alpha = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation ($2\alpha + \alpha - 2\alpha =4$) says that the point $(\alpha, \alpha, \alpha)$ is on the plane. You solved it correctly, to get $\alpha =4$, and the point $(4,4,4,)$ is indeed on the plane. But you wanted a point on the norml line, so, what you wanted to say, I think, is that the point $\alpha(2,1,-2)$ is on the plane. The equation that expresses this condition is $4\alpha + \alpha + 4 \alpha = 4$, as ronno said.